# /usr/bin/php vs /bin/php vs php in bash

Tags: php, php-cli

We are running a php client command. **php xx yy zz run** just fine but not its counter parts (/usr/bin/php and /bin/php) which give very weird error.

I am so confused row, given that :

```
command -v php || which php || type -p php
```

=> /usr/bin/php (( all 3 of them)

```
whereis php
```

=> php: /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php7.3 /usr/lib/php /etc/php /usr/include/php /usr/share/php /usr/share/php7.3-xmlrpc /usr/share/php7.3-imap /usr/share/php7.3-opcache /usr/share/php7.3-zip /usr/share/php7.3-curl /usr/share/php7.3-common /usr/share/php7.3-bcmath /usr/share/php7.3-soap /usr/share/php7.2-xml /usr/share/php7.3-gd /usr/share/php7.3-mysql /usr/share/php7.3-mbstring /usr/share/php7.2-common /usr/share/php7.3-json /usr/share/php7.3-xml /usr/share/php7.3-readline /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz

```
type -a php
```

=> php is /usr/bin/php

php is /bin/php

Why my script works with "php" but /usr/bin/php or /bin/php.  What are the different between them ?

Comment: Difference between what? Your output shows only one `php` command, namely `/usr/bin/php`. All others are just directories, configuration files, libraries, manuals, etc. What is the `weird error` you get when you use the given commands? Don't interpret it, just run the commands and copy&paste the output into your question.

Comment: i would suggest to use `whereis php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, there are two ways `php` is installed on your lets say Linux system.
For `apache` use for webserver. And for `cli` use.

You can check the web version using `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` function for a web page.

For `cli` you can check path and version using `which php` and `php --version` respactivitly.

#### Difference php-cgi and php-cli

> PHP CLI is the command-line interface for PHP (e.g. for creating standalone applications)
>   PHP CGI is the common gateway interface for PHP (e.g. for web applications)
>   Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9315749/2107145

You might want to read this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45493656/2107145 for details of all `php` version.

#### Explaination of commands

`type`: will display information about command

`which`: will display binary path of given command

`command`: display information about command

`whereis`: will find all binaries of given command say `php`

thats all for now.

Ask me if you need to know more.